# Can I rename files in a directory with Vim?

Tags: linux, vim, rename, batch-rename

If I open a directory in `vim` using `vim .` I will get a file-browser-type interface of the current directory.  From there I am expected to browse to a file, and then start editing it.

I want to use this interface to rename files.  Normal `vim` rename works like `%s/term1/term2/`, but when I try it out here, it returns: `E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off`.

Is there a way to turn `modifiable` on in this scenario, or does this simply mean that it cannot be done like this with vim?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it can't be done like that.

That "file-browser-type interface" is provided by a built-in plugin called netrw. It is read-only so yeah, you can't modify it.

You are supposed to hit `R` to rename the file under the cursor or the marked files.

See `:help netrw`, `:help netrw-browse-maps` and more specifically `:help netrw-R`.

If you want to batch-rename files using Vim you should try `qmv` from the [renameutils](http://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/) package or `vidir` from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package (thanks to Dmitry for the heads up).

Comment: Yea, that makes sense.  I'll look at qmv!

Comment: N. B. `qmv` has [some troubles](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734189) with non-ascii characters, while `vidir` from `moreutils` has not.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [renamer.vim - Use the power of vim to rename groups of files](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1721) plugin (now purely maintained on [GitHub](https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-renamer)). Like *netrw*, it presents the directory contents in a scratch buffer, and then lets you edit that buffer, and finally apply the edits to the underlying files.

Comment: https://github.com/qpkorr/vim-renamer is the new location.  The vim.org link is outdated.

Comment: @AndrewKeeton: Thanks, added that link. The vim.org refers to it, too, but it's convenient to directly add it here, too. Though I really like the central vim.org repository, many plugins now directly use GitHub exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Netrw will allow you to apply a pattern to rename files since about v143.  The procedure:  mark files (use mr to mark files based on a pattern), then hit R.  Upon the first renaming query, respond with the string`s/-frompat-/-topat-/` where the `-frompat-` and `-topat-` are vim substitution patterns.  The `s/`
 is required for this.  Example:

```
s/\(.*\)\.c/\1.cpp/
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to use "system()" to accomplish this task using the shell (if that is the case, of course) creating a function to accomplish this task on your ".vimrc".

```
func! YourFunc() range

    let l:result = system("your shell command")

    [...]

endfunc
```

See an use of "system()" in https://github.com/eduardolucioac/groovim/blob/master/.vimrc

[]'s